# Cleaning Up Bad Answers on Popular Questions

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions

> ## Due to graduation, privilege levels have dropped to the point where most of us can no longer delete answers making this less productive. We can revisit it in the future when we have more 20k+ users.

Back in May 2012, Rarity asked about how we should deal with bad or "me too" answers:

[Do we need a policy on bad/"me too" answers?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269/do-we-need-a-policy-on-bad-me-too-answers)

More recently, bad deleted posts pushed one of enderland's questions in to CW mode causing much gnashing of teeth:

[Un-community wiki this question?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2278/un-community-wiki-this-question)

When questions here get popular, they get a lot of views, and a lot of answers because of the subjective nature of this site and the feeling that anyone is qualified to post their opinion as an answer. While [gnat is leading the charge to solve the hot question issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216260/reorder-questions-picked-for-hot-list-based-on-adjusted-hotness-score-discard-s), in the meantime something we can do is clean up these posts with tons of answers, and improve the quality of the site for people looking at some of our most popular questions.

I have [run a query](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2286/7945) showing the number of posts we have with each range of answers. Here are the results for posts that have never been closed:

> [image: Graph of Query Results]

I am going to wager that a question with 25 answers probably has a lot of answers that are less than ideal. But don't take my word for it, [see the post](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1478/how-can-i-overcome-years-of-experience-requirements-when-applying-to-positions). Not to pick on anyone, but is [this answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/1482/7945) really worthy of 6 upvotes when compared with the other answers in the question? I would wager not.

What I want to do is, starting from the questions with the most answers, get the community (that means you!) focused on cleaning up one per week. This is my proposed workflow:

1. I will list direct links to the question and each answer, and the starting score
2. For the week, I would love your cooperation in voting on as many of those answers as possible
3. Any answer that does not offer anything unique compared to the other answers should be downvoted since the downvote text is 'This answer is not useful'
4. Any obvious mistakes (formatting, typos, grammar) should be fixed with an edit
5. At the end of the week (Friday Japan Time, Thursday US Time) I will show the *change in score* between the starting point, and the ending point
6. Questions that have dropped below -1 can be voted by trusted users, -3 by normal users -- bad answers should get a vote for deletion so it gets sent to the queue
7. We can then go through the review queues to finalize any deletes that didn't get completed during the review
8. Answers that had a large negative drop but remain positive can be reviewed by the mods who can delete them anyway (we can always undelete or create separate meta discussions if merited)
9. If the number of answers drops, CW status for the question can be removed (if desired) to encourage future users to contribute quality answers

<sup>Appreciated but not required is flagging comments that say things like [*"+1 for mentioning that skills do not increase in direct proportion to experience."*](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1478/how-can-i-overcome-years-of-experience-requirements-when-applying-to-positions#comment3189_1503)</sup>

I plan to start this project next week. If you have any concerns, or can improve the workflow, or otherwise have a good idea on how to do this in a better way, share it here. Starting next week we will go through the questions one by one until we end up with a better resource. If you are willing to contribute what shouldn't be more than 20 minutes a week to this, please add a comment and show support.

Here is the data for how many questions have each amount of answers, and a link to an advanced search to find them (only questions with more than 10 answers listed):

- 25 Answers: [1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Afalse+answers%3A25..25)
- 23 Answers: [1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Afalse+answers%3A23..23)
- 19 Answers: [2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Afalse+answers%3A19..19)
- 18 Answers: [1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Afalse+answers%3A18..18)
- 17 Answers: [2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Afalse+answers%3A17..17)
- 16 Answers: [1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Afalse+answers%3A16..16)
- 15 Answers: [5](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Afalse+answers%3A15..15)
- 14 Answers: [8](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Afalse+answers%3A14..14)
- 13 Answers: [4](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Afalse+answers%3A13..13)
- 12 Answers: [12](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Afalse+answers%3A12..12)
- 11 Answers: [13](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Afalse+answers%3A11..11)
- 10 Answers: [26](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Afalse+answers%3A10..10)

At that pace we can get all questions down to under 15 answers (the Community Wiki threshold) by Spring, meaning that we can manage future answers by searching every now and again for questions with over 15 answers.

Comment: Good idea, we want to set a good example for questions and answers. Count me in! Though i am hesitant about arbitrarily making everything less than 15, if they are good answers i wouldnt want them deleted for the sake of it

Comment: This is awesome. I really like how you're focusing on one question at a time in its own thread.

Comment: Since the answer you singled out was posted among the first, it could have been very useful at the time and wasn't actually *compared* to the others. Not sure how to deal with such situations however.

Comment: For the sake of "precision," maybe there should be a down vote reason like "this answer is useful but another is FAR better."  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [How can I overcome "years of experience" requirements when applying to positions?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1478/)

**Created:** May 29 '12 at 12:55
**Score:** +141
**Views:** 49,533
**Answers:** 19

### Results

A total of 22 votes were placed on this question, no answers were dropped in to the negatives, and none were deleted. Here is the change:

1. [( ― ) 5 → 5](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1479)
2. [( ― ) 3 → 3](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1480)
3. [( ― ) 4 → 4](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1482)
4. [( ― ) 10 → 10](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1483)
5. [(▲4) 53 → 57](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1484)
6. [(▲5) 165 → 170](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1485)
7. [( ― ) 15 → 15](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1487)
8. [(▲1) 38 → 39](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1488)
9. [(▼1) 2 → 1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1489)
10. [( ― ) 0 → 0](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1490)
11. [( ― ) 3 → 3](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1497)
12. [(▼1) 1 → 0](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1501)
13. [( ― ) 4 → 4](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1503)
14. [( ― ) 2 → 2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1504)
15. [( ― ) 2 → 2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1533)
16. [(▼1) 1 → 0](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1556)
17. [(▲2) 18 → 20](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3318)
18. [(▼1) 2 → 1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3348)
19. [( ― ) 5 → 5](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7279)

---

1. [Initial Score: 5](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1479)
2. [Initial Score: 3](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1480) [image: edited]
3. [Initial Score: 4](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1482)
4. [Initial Score: 10](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1483) [image: edited]
5. [Initial Score: 53](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1484) [image: edited]
6. [Initial Score: 165](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1485) [image: edited]
7. [Initial Score: 15](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1487) [image: edited]
8. [Initial Score: 38](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1488) [image: edited]
9. [Initial Score: 2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1489) [image: edited]
10. [Initial Score: 0](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1490)
11. [Initial Score: 3](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1497)
12. [Initial Score: 1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1501)
13. [Initial Score: 4](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1503)
14. [Initial Score: 2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1504) [image: edited]
15. [Initial Score: 2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1533)
16. [Initial Score: 1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1556) [image: edited]
17. [Initial Score: 18](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3318) [image: edited]
18. [Initial Score: 2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3348) [image: edited]
19. [Initial Score: 5](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7279)

Answer (score 3):

> ## Please vote to delete the bad answers, and if any answers require mod intervention or flagging of comments, please flag as need-be so we can move on to the next question next week.

### Results

We placed [57 votes](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/1478/timeline) on the question this week for a net change of -10 in the score of the answers in the question. Two answers were deleted, and 4 additional answers can be deleted (negative score) dropping the answer total from 25 to 19. Personally I think too many marginal answers were upvoted despite not contributing anything to the quality of the Q&A on the question. Moving forward, let's remember that if there are 19 answers, people are not going to read all 19, so it is very important we make the good answers more visible by downvoting/deleting marginal answers with no added value.

Here is the result of each answer:

1. [(▼2) 7 → 5](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1479)
2. [(▼3) 7 → 4](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1480)
3. [(▼2) 6 → 4](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1482)
4. [( ― ) 10 → 10](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1483)
5. [( ― ) 51 → 51](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1484)
6. [(▲4) 160 → 164](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1485)
7. [(▲1) 14 → 15](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1487)
8. [(▲4) 33 → 37](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1488)
9. [(▼1) 3 → 2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1489)
10. [(▼1) 2 → 1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1490)
11. <strike>[(▼3) 1 → -2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1494)</strike>
12. [( ― ) 4 → 4](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1497)
13. <strike>[(▼2) 1 → -1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1499)</strike>
14. [(▼1) 2 → 1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1501)
15. <strike>[(▼2) 0 → -2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1502)</strike>
16. [(▼2) 6 → 4](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1503)
17. [( ― ) 2 → 2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1504)
18. <strike>[(▼1) -8 → -9](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1507)</strike>
19. [(▲1) 1 → 2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1533)
20. [(▼1) 2 → 1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1556)
21. [(▲4) 12 → 16](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3318)
22. <strike>[(▼3) 2 → -1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3327)</strike>
23. [( ― ) 2 → 2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3348)
24. <strike>[(▼2) 0 → -2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3397)</strike>
25. [(▲2) 2 → 4](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7279)

---

### [How can I overcome "years of experience" requirements when applying to positions?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1478)

**Created:** May 29 '12 at 12:55
**Score:** +137
**Views:** 48,044
**Answers:** 25

1. [Initial Score: 7](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1479)
2. [Initial Score: 7](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1480)
3. [Initial Score: 6](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1482)
4. [Initial Score: 10](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1483) [image: edited]
5. [Initial Score: 51](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1484) [image: edited]
6. [Initial Score: 160](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1485) [image: edited]
7. [Initial Score: 14](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1487) [image: edited]
8. [Initial Score: 33](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1488) [image: edited]
9. [Initial Score: 3](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1489)
10. [Initial Score: 2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1490)
11. [Initial Score: 1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1494)
12. [Initial Score: 4](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1497)
13. [Initial Score: 1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1499)
14. [Initial Score: 2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1501)
15. [Initial Score: 0](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1502)
16. [Initial Score: 6](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1503)
17. [Initial Score: 2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1504) [image: edited]
18. [Initial Score: -8](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1507)
19. [Initial Score: 1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1533)
20. [Initial Score: 2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1556) [image: edited]
21. [Initial Score: 12](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3318) [image: edited]
22. [Initial Score: 2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3327)
23. [Initial Score: 2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3348) [image: edited]
24. [Initial Score: 0](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3397)
25. [Initial Score: 2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7279)

Comment: What do the little pencils mean?

Comment: @jmort It means it's been edited. While I find it unlikely, it's possible someone could make a bad first answer, and then steal ideas from other answers in a later edit to make it look better. While I posted them in original creation order, the ones that are edited may require a wee bit of added scrutiny. (see the little mark next to this comment? same image, same meaning, you can mouseover them to see the time they were edited)

Comment: Hmmm, one of the posts that has a pencil beside it doesn't appear to have been edited when you look at the post itself. Maybe it's because the user's account is deleted...

Comment: @jmort, which one? I used [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/workplace/revision/162224/206771/links-and-score-of-all-answers-for-a-question) and compared activity date to answer date. If it hasn't been edited, I'll have to look at the query data. Which number was it?

Comment: Number 2. Look at number 2...

Comment: Ah, it's not a deleted user. The post was migrated from Programmers SE.

Comment: [timeline](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timeline) view can be helpful to track voting on answers: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/1478/timeline

Comment: @gnat, that is tremendous. Another tool to use to prove the huge influx of votes from a hot post. Wow! Thanks.

Comment: @jmort, ah, it seems migration counts as activity. Not much I can do about that without going through them manually. Not good enough at SQL to figure out how to foo the bar to prevent that from occurring at any rate. Shouldn't be too much of a problem (I hope), but I'll take a look at migration date in the future if I realize a similar issue. (for now I removed the edit mark on post #2)

Comment: yeah. Especially sad to see how basically any answer, no matter how bad, gets a solid portion of _sympathy upvotes_ from passers by. ["...there are just too many new voters and commenters to get things going as designed"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164078/165773)

Answer (score 2):

### [How can I encourage a culture of punctuality in a software company?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/450/how-can-i-encourage-a-culture-of-punctuality-in-a-software-company)

**Created:** Apr 12 '12 at 17:34
**Score:** +72
**Views:** 19,143
**Answers:** 23

#### Results:

We placed 73 votes, deleted 6 answers, and made a net score change of +9 to the question. Here are the results of each answer:

1. [(▼2) 5 → 3](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/452)
2. [(▲3) 43 → 46](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/453)
3. [(▲1) 110 → 111](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/461)
4. [(▲8) 90 → 98](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/509)
5. <strike>[( ― ) 21 → 21](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/510)</strike>
6. [(▼1) 19 → 18](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/514)
7. [( ― ) 9 → 9](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/546)
8. [(▲2) 13 → 15](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/895)
9. [(▲2) 4 → 6](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/904)
10. [(▼1) 0 → -1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/941) <sup>[please delete me](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/941)</sup>
11. [(▲2) 6 → 8](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1003)
12. [(▲2) 16 → 18](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1018)
13. [(▲4) 36 → 40](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1179)
14. [( ― ) 7 → 7](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1184)
15. <strike>[(▼2) 9 → 7](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1188)</strike>
16. <strike>[(▼6) 10 → 4](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2440)</strike>
17. [(▲2) 9 → 11](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2442)
18. [(▲2) 28 → 30](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2443)
19. <strike>[(▼3) -2 → -5](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2444)</strike>
20. [(▲3) 8 → 11](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2458)
21. <strike>[(▼3) 2 → -1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2522)</strike>
22. [(▼1) 6 → 5](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2563)
23. <strike>[(▼3) 0 → -3](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6771)</strike>

---

1. [Initial Score: 5](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/452) [image: edited]
2. [Initial Score: 43](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/453)
3. [Initial Score: 110](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/461)
4. [Initial Score: 90](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/509) [image: edited]
5. [Initial Score: 21](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/510) [image: edited]
6. [Initial Score: 19](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/514)
7. [Initial Score: 9](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/546) [image: edited]
8. [Initial Score: 13](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/895)
9. [Initial Score: 4](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/904)
10. [Initial Score: 0](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/941)
11. [Initial Score: 6](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1003)
12. [Initial Score: 16](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1018) [image: edited]
13. [Initial Score: 36](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1179)
14. [Initial Score: 7](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1184) [image: edited]
15. [Initial Score: 9](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1188)
16. [Initial Score: 10](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2440)
17. [Initial Score: 9](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2442)
18. [Initial Score: 28](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2443) [image: edited]
19. [Initial Score: -2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2444)
20. [Initial Score: 8](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2458)
21. [Initial Score: 2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2522) [image: edited]
22. [Initial Score: 6](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2563) [image: edited]
23. [Initial Score: 0](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6771) [image: edited]

Comment: There seems to be a flood of "Not an answer" flags on answers on this post. Many of the answers so flagged were, in fact, trying to answer the question. If they're low quality, downvote instead please.

Comment: @Yami, created a separate discussion [here](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2321/when-asked-how-can-i-foo-the-bar-is-dont-foo-the-bar-an-appropriate-answer). I personally disagree (I think a half-dozen of those flags at least were mine), but we'll see what the community thinks.